# Sympy: There remains some terms which shuold be obviously vanished

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to calculate derivative of a function using following code.

```py
import sympy


pi = sympy.symbols("pi")
class H(sympy.Function):
    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        x = self.args[0]
        return - sympy.functions.exp(-sympy.Pow(x, 2) / 2) / sympy.sqrt(2 * pi)

def G(a):
    return (
        (a + 1) * H(1 / sympy.sqrt(a))
        - sympy.sqrt(a / (2 * pi)) * sympy.functions.exp(-1 / (2 * a))
    )

x = sympy.symbols("x")
sympy.simplify(sympy.diff(G(x), x))
```

It is expected to be `G'(x) = H(1 / sqrt(x))`, but I got

```py
Out[1]: H(1/sqrt(x)) - sqrt(2)*sqrt(x/pi)*exp(-1/(2*x))/(4*x) - sqrt(2)*sqrt(x/pi)*exp(-1/(2*x))/(4*x**2) + sqrt(2)*exp(-1/(2*x))/(4*sqrt(pi)*sqrt(x)) + sqrt(2)*exp(-1/(2*x))/(4*sqrt(pi)*x**(3/2))
```

The remaining terms should obviously be 0 when seen by human eye.

Then I tried to change two `pi`s in the definition of H and G to `sympy.pi`, which returns `H(1 / sqrt(x))` as I expected.

Why my first code returns some extra terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy has built in rules which allow certain transformations to happen (automatically, sometimes) or to be prohibited (by default). When you defined `pi` as a Symbol, you created a generic symbol with the only assumption being that it is commutative. But the number `pi` is that *and* it is positive. That assumption allows something like `sqrt(x/y)` to automatically rewrite as `sqrt(y)*sqrt(x)/y` if `y` is positive:

```
>>> sqrt(x/y)
sqrt(x/y)
>>> sqrt(x/3)
sqrt(3)*sqrt(x)/3
```

If you take your last expression and substitution a positive value for the symbol `pi` you will get that rewrite and then the cancelling terms will cancel.

```
>>> print(sympy.simplify(sympy.diff(G(x), x))).subs(pi, 3)
H(1/sqrt(x))
```

As Johan points out, it is better in this case to just use SymPy's `S.Pi`:

```
>>> S.Pi.n(3)
3.14
```